# Continious subbundle

Tags: vector-spaces

> > Let $W$ be a vector bundle with base $\Omega$ and projection $p$. A *continious subbundle* of $W$ is a subset $W_0$ of $W$ such that $p|W_0$ defines a vector bundle *over* $\Omega$.

Now here is something I do not understand:

> > If $W=\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^n$, a continious subbundle (of dimension $r$) is a continious map from $\Omega$ to the Grassmannian $G_{n,r}$.

Could you please explain this sentence to me?

Answer (score 1):

The [Grassmannian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $G_{n,r}$ is the space of $r$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a continuous rank $r$ subbundle $V$ of $\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^n$, for each point $x\in\Omega$, the definition implies that the fiber of $V$ over $x$, i.e. $(\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}^n) \cap V$, is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $r$. Define a map $f:\Omega\to G_{n,r}$ by assigning to $x$ the point in $G_{n,r}$ defined by the subspace $(\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}^n) \cap V$. Then the fact that $V$ is a continuous subbundle can be used to show that $f$ is continuous. Intuitively, the fact that $V$ is itself a vector bundle over $\Omega$ (and in particular is locally trivial) means that if $x$ is close to $y$ in $\Omega$, then the fiber $f(x)$ must be close to the fiber $f(y)$ in $G_{n,r}$. The details are a little cumbersome and come down to describing the topology of $G_{n,r}$, but it would be a good exercise if you haven't worked with Grassmannians before.

For the other direction, if you are given a continuous map $f:\Omega\to G_{n,r}$, then for each $x\in\Omega$, the point $f(x)$ is an $r$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define a subset $V$ of $\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^n$ by setting
$$
  V = \{ (x, v) \in \Omega \times\mathbb{R}^n : v \in f(x) \}.
$$
That is, the fiber of $V$ over the point $x$ is the set of all vectors $v$ in the $r$-dimensional subspace given by $f(v)$. In the same way as the other direction, you can use the fact that $f$ is continuous to show that $V$ is a continuous subbundle of $\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, the fact that $f(x)$ varies continuously with $x$ can be used to show local triviality.

Very intuitively, this statement says: "a continuous rank-$r$ subbundle of a trivial bundle is given by assigning an $r$-dimensional subspace of the fiber to each point $x$ of the base in a way that depends continuously on $x$." The hidden details are in what is meant by an assignment of subspaces that depends continuously on $x$, and are given by the topology of the Grassmannian.

Comment: Is that meant that the r-dim. continuous subbundle $W_0$ can be described by a continuous map $f\colon\Omega\to G_r(\mathbb{R}^n), \omega\mapsto F_{\omega}:=\left\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n: (\omega,y)\in W_0\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: By the way: Why is it called a **continuous** subbundle? In the definition of vector bundle (when describing it as a function into $G_{n,t}(V)$) the function $f$ is always assumed to be continous and (when describing it by projection from the total room top the basis) the projection is always assumed to be continuous, too. So why the extra addition **continuous** here?

Comment: Your first comment is correct. The function $f$ assigns to each point in $\Omega$ a point in the Grassmannian, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the fiber of the subbundle over that point.

Comment: Regarding the second comment about the notion of continuous: I agree, a 'non-continuous' subbundle doesn't make any sense, so usually, one would just say `subbundle.' My guess is that the term is used here to stress the fact that the choice of subspaces must depend continuously on the base point and can't just be arbitrary. Also, in other contexts, one might use 'continuous subbundle' to distinguish from the stronger 'smooth subbundle,' but my guess is that this isn't relevant here.